# Accept promotion and wait for a better offer?

Tags: salary, job-hopping

I recently got a promotion and the salary is still about $15,000 under market value. The promotion is technically a new job as I am moving to a new position / location. I tried to negotiate a higher salary, but it only got me $5000 more...

My plan is to accept this promotion, move to the new location (which I like), then continue my job search.

If something comes along that is at market value I'll take it.

Is there anything wrong with this? I don't want to be a job hopper, but they are seriously undervaluing my skill; there are interns coming out of college making more than I am in the same company.

Comment: You don't tell how long you have been working at your company, and what qualification and job you have, and in what country.

Comment: Everything you are doing is perfect.  Follow your plan.  As soon as possible, move to a company that pays you properly - and never look back.

Comment: Are they paying moving expenses?

Comment: @MisterPositive yes, but it's only an hour away

Answer (score 4):

I can't see anything wrong with that. It seems like the most sensible solution. I think that you have answered your own question. So, I think that you have already reached your own conclusion & are just looking for us to confirm your judgement.

What are your alternatives?

- quit? With no job offer you are not likely to do that.
- refuse the promotion? Then you can't move to the more desirable city
- negotiate for more? You already tried that. Even if you try again, it seems incredibly unlikely that you would get the extra $10k you are looking for.

That really only leave the option you suggest - accept the offer, move to the better city and start looking for work there.

Comment: Seems legit to me.

Comment: haha, guess what, I just found out today that I got an offer to stay here and it pays $15,000 more than the promotion. Now I surely don't know what to do.

Comment: Yay!!! Gratz!!!  Post an answer to tell how you did it, and accept it :-)  Forgotten the "better" city? :-)